# Remove continuously repeating values

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to remove continuously repeating values? Not just repeating values with *unique()* function.

So for example, I want:

```
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,2
```

to become

```
0,1,2,3,2,1,2
```

and not just

```
0,1,2,3
```

Is there a word to describe this? I'm sure that the solution is out there somewhere and I just can't find it because I don't know the word for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a value when it's difference from the previous value is not zero (and keep the first one):

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,2)
x[c(1, diff(x)) != 0]

# [1] 0 1 2 3 2 1 2
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly.  So I guess the term is consecutive. Can't believe I forgot about it. I'll delete this post soon. Sorry for the duplicate :(

Comment: @Robo You shouldn't delete: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: THis solution fails if vector is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2)
rle(v)$values
```

Output:

```
[1] 0 1 2 3 2 1 2
```

Comment: This one also work perfectly! Thank you

Comment: This question had already beeen marked as a duplicate of another one which has as an accepted solution this precise method.

Comment: @snoram Most likely mpalanco didn't see it marked as duplicated when posting the answer.

Comment: @snoram yes, sorry, no need to downvote, as zx8754 said, I did not see it marked as duplicate. AFAIK if it is marked as a duplicate I wouldn't have been able to post an answer. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. It showed it was marked as duplicate 3 minutes earlier... but I understand that is not a lot of time.